# Populate DropDownListFor and default value is guid parameter

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5, guid, html.dropdownlistfor

I have populated a DropDownListFor with all the correct values.  I'm passing a Guid parameter, but don't know how to set the default value to that Guid.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Parent)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Parent, new SelectList(Model.AllParents, "Id", "Name"), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent)
</div>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
     public List<Parent> AllParents { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Parent")]
     public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(Guid? id)
{

            var parentViewModel = new ParentViewModel
            {
                AllParents = _Service.GetAll().ToList()
            };
            return View(parentViewModel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to replace `string.Empty` with "Default value do you want"     `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Parent, new SelectList(Model.AllParents, "Id", "Name"), "Default value is here here", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: geez...completely overlooked that.    copy and paste in form of answer so I can give you credit.     Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace string.Empty with "Default value do you want"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Parent, new SelectList(Model.AllParents, "Id", "Name"), "Default value is here here", new { @class = "form-control" })
```